# Can minidlna play random tracks?

Tags: music, upnp, dlna

I have my music on a small NAS, which includes a version of minidlna, and I listen over UPnP. My client will play albums, artists and playlists etc.
I cannot upgrade either the server nor the client, nor use any other transport or protocol.

I would like to be able to play a random selection of music each day, but neither the server nor the client have this feature. How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Minidlna stores data in sqlite tables that can be accessed directly by any user.
Using the installed `sqlite3` application with a suitable SQL query can generate a simple m3u playlist, which in turn can be scanned by minidlna.

For example:

```
sqlite3 -list /tmp/minidlna/files.db "select path from details where track>0 order by random() limit 1000" > /home/user/music/random\ playlist.m3u
```

I needed `-list` to avoid quotes around file names and `track>0` to filter out records that do not refer to audio tracks, though there is probably a more robust way to do this.

If the generated m3u playlist file is within the minidlna scanned directories, it will be picked up via inotify and served automatically.

This approach could be developed to include only specific genres or other criteria, effectively adding a 'smart playlist' feature.

Add this command to the crontab for a user who has write access to the music directory in order to run daily / hourly. The downside is that my nas loses crontabs on reboot, but this is rare.

Different installations of minidlna may keep data in /var instead.